# Change bullet point symbol without changing \item

Tags: beamer, itemize

I have the following code:

```
 \documentclass{beamer}




\usepackage{pifont}


\begin {document}
\frame{
    \frametitle{Test}
\begin{itemize}
\item test
\item test
\end{itemize}
}

\end{document}
```

Now I want to change the bullet points to another form, using `\ding{111}` and pifont:

```
\usepackage{pifont}
```

According to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822345/how-do-you-change-the-image-of-a-bullet-point-in-latex-beamer) I tried

```
\newcommand{\myitem}{\item[\checkmark]}
```

but than I have to change every `\item` in my presentation to `\myitem`, so how can I do this without needing to change the `\item`?

Comment: This question appears to be out of scope because the author found his own solution by reading the existing documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I just found it out by reading the complete post:

```
\usepackage{pifont}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}{\ding{111}}
```

Sorry!